# \lstinputlisting doesn't format first line

Tags: pdftex, listings

When compiling my document including a source code file with `\lstinputlisting{source_file.cs}` the first line is not formatted correctly.  If I go into the file and add a blank line to the top, the first line of code is now the second line in the file and is formatted correctly, however I now have a gap at the top of the frame around the code.  All my searches for this problem have returned info on the `firstline` option (to only include certain lines of code) which is not what I'm after.  Any ideas?

EDIT: Just tried this in a new doc for a MWE but it works fine.  Checked what the differences were and turns out the source files were created with UTF-8 BOM encoding, changing to UTF-8 fixed the issue.

Comment: show the problematic file ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a BOM at the beginning of the file